# how to use AVKit to playback the HTTP stream video

Tags: ios, swift

```
   var url:NSURL! = NSURL(string: "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8")
        var playItem:AVPlayerItem! = AVPlayerItem(URL: url);
        var player:AVPlayer! = AVPlayer(playerItem: playItem);

        var playerLayer:AVPlayerLayer! = AVPlayerLayer(player: player);
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer);
        player.play()
```

when i run these code, there will be crash, could anyone told me how to use AVKit to playback the video? Thx ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
//stream url
    let movieUrl:NSURL? = NSURL (string: "http://YOUR URL")
    if let url = movieUrl {
      self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
      self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer
    }

//Button action
@IBAction func live(sender: UIButton) {


    self.presentViewController(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
    }
```